# how update some field in ef

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

If there is a entity named `UserInfo`， `UserId` is the primary key， I defined entity as following

```
UserInfo userInfonew = new UserInfo()
{
    UserId=userInfo.UserId,
    Email = userInfo.Email,
    FirstName = userInfo.FirstName,
    LastName = userInfo.LastName,
    LastUpdateBy = GetCurrentUserGuid(),
    LastUpdate = DateTime.Now
};
```

If we want to update all entity fields, we have method as follows

```
db.Entry(userInfonew).State = EntityState.Modified;

db.SaveChanges();
```

If we want to update some fields, for example, we just want to update email field：

```
db.UserInfoes.Attach(userInfonew);

db.Entry(userInfonew).Property(x => x.Email).IsModified = true;
db.SaveChanges();
```

But if there are 20 fields in this entity, if we want to update 18 fields, the two fields left don't need update, we have to write 18 times about `db.Entry(userInfonew).Property(x => x.field).IsModified = true`, is there any way about this? I don't want to write so many times about this.

Comment: Why not use EF change tracking as it was intended? Query the user, update any properties you need, call `SaveChanges`. EF will do the rest.

Comment: IF you can't use change tracking, you can actually also set the Entity state of your whole entry to Modified if you still have the original values of your entry. If you do not have your original data and want to control the generated query to actually just update the specific fields, you will have to set each property to modified.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not get original data from source and if properties which you do not want to update are known, you can actually use *Reflection* to achieve what you want. What you have to do is create an *extension method* (can also be ordinary method if you prefer so) which changes state of properties as below:

```
public static void SetPropertiesToModeified<TEntity>(
    this MyContext context, 
    TEntity entity,
    List<string> propertiesNotToUpdate)
{
    // Get properties to update. Get all properties and
    // exclude the ones you do not want to update.
    List<string> propertiesToUpdate = typeof(TEntity)
        .GetProperties()                
        .Select(m => m.Name)        
        .Except(propertiesNotToUpdate) // exculde propeties not update
        .ToList();

    DbEntityEntry<TEntity> entry = context.Entry(entity);
    propertiesToUpdate.ForEach(
        p => entry.Property(p).IsModified = true);
}
```

Then, you can use it like:

```
using(MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
{
    UserInfo userInfo = .....;
    context.UserInfoes.Attach(userInfo);
    List<string> propertiesNotToUpdate = new List<string>
    {
        "UserId",
        "RegistrationDate"
    };
    context.SetPropertiesToModeified(userInfo, propertiesNotToUpdate);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Change Tracking in Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx).